# Method Math.random - how it work?

Tags: java

Some teacher today teach us how work Math.random in Java language. I don't understand what he told. Can some explain? I have some code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random random = new Random();

        double r = Math.random() * 4.4 + 1.2;
        System.out.println(r);

    }
}
```

Next he ask us what is interval of this random. We don't know and he write:

```
<1.2, 5.6> --> <0, 4.4> + 1.2 --> double r = Math.random() * 4.4 + 1.2;
```

How can I calculate this, what is mathematical formula? `<1.2, 5.6> --> <0, 4.4> + 1.2`

Comment: Please, read [this discussion on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions/253896#comment17104_253896) for understanding why "Explain this code to me" questions are off-topic and not useful.

Comment: You should probably talk to your teacher if you do not understand the material.

Comment: I doubt there is any complex "mathematical formular" for what you are asking. It should be pretty self evident that creating a random number between 1.2 and 5.6 is the same as creating a random number between 0 and 4.4 and adding 1.2. You just subtract the lower bound and then later add it again.

Answer (score 1):

Math.random() gives a random number between 0 and 1. Actually it's a pseudo random but that's a different story. So in order to have a random number for example between 0 and 100 you need to multiply Math.random() by 100.

That makes you range from 0..1 to 0..100   because 0x100=0 and 1x100=100.

By adding a number to the result you set the lower boundary of the range. For example if you want a number between 100 and 200 you can do:

Math.random()*100 + 100.

So in your case he multiplies it by 4.4 giving it a range 0->4.4 and then adds 1.2 giving it a lower boundary of 1.2 which makes the actual range 1.2->5.6

Comment: And in general: `random() * (upper - lower) + lower`.

Comment: yeah ;) that's probably more a question for the maths teacher than the programming teacher

Comment: Thanks Veselin :)